# How to UPDATE JSON column completely in MySql 5.7?

Tags: mysql-5.7

I am new to MySQL 5.7. I have a table with a JSON column.

data:{"Game": "Cricket","Player":"Dhoni"}

This is just a sample JSON object but I have plenty of key,value pairs in my column.

I want to replace my JSON completely with new JSON object that I am receiving as a response from some API

e.g. 
{"Game": "Hockey","Player":"Kohli","":"",..........}

Please suggest a method for the same.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the JSON completely in MySQL version >= 5.7, simply use the UPDATE query and it will work.

For example:

```
UPDATE json_table SET json = '{"Game": "Hockey","Player":"Kohli"}' (WHERE CLAUSE)
```